# display already created Mysql database table with Django

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

I am very beginner in Django. I have just questions. I search and watched a lot of videos about Django and there tutors were creating classes for database then run it and boom, in the database and in the table there were columns. What if I already have a table and I just want to display . Is this possible ? So my goal is to display my table from database with pagination and then possibility to make querying. if there is any example of it can you show me ? Maybe something like github project or anything that helps me . Thank you in advance. Have a good day.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is use this command to help you build model from existing tables in database with `managed=False` in the meta options

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/